# Time stamp on messages as they are sent in Akka

Tags: scala, akka

I am building a distributed multi-agent market simulator using Akka and would like to timestamp all messages between my actors. Does Akka natively support time stamping messages?

Comment: AFAIK, no, but you can create a base message class that does have a timestamp field on it and then extend all of your other messages from it.

Comment: @cmbaxter Thanks for the suggestion.  This is in fact the solution that I have implemented for now.  Am hoping that there is a better way...

Comment: The blog entry about the "spider pattern" http://letitcrash.com/post/30585282971/discovering-message-flows-in-actor-systems-with might be interesting to you, in that it wraps messages in custom envelopes and then unwraps on the receiving side.